# SQL Server 2008: Custom Aggregate Function and Indexed Views

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sqlclr

I'm having issues creating an index on a view that uses a custom CLR aggregate function.

I don't see any way to flag the aggregate function as deterministic or with schemabinding.

I'm creating my function like so:

```
CREATE ASSEMBLY StringUtil
AUTHORIZATION dbo
FROM 'C:\StringUtil.dll'
WITH PERMISSION_SET = UNSAFE
GO

CREATE AGGREGATE SUMSTRING (@input nvarchar(200)) 
RETURNS nvarchar(max) WITH SCHEMABINDING 
EXTERNAL NAME StringUtil.Concatenate
```

And my view is defined as:

```
CREATE VIEW RolledValues WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
SELECT ID, SumString(ValueText) as Value FROM [dbo].[IDValue]
GROUP BY ID
```

The issue occurs when I try to create an index on that view:

```
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX IDX_RollValues_ID_VALUE on RolledValues (ID)

Error:  Cannot create index on view "dbo.RolledValues" because it uses aggregate
"dbo.SumString". Consider eliminating the aggregate, not indexing the view, or 
using alternate aggregates.
```

So is it possible to use a custom aggregate function in an indexed view?  I cannot find any documentation on this...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The page on [Creating Indexed Views](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191432.aspx) lists a number of restrictions:

> The SELECT statement in the view cannot contain the following Transact-SQL syntax elements:
>
> ...
>
> A CLR user-defined aggregate function.

There's not even provision, at the current time, to describe a CLR aggregate as Deterministic (at least, if the API was going to be consistent). The [SqlFunctionAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.server.sqlfunctionattribute.aspx) has an `IsDeterministic` property. No such property exists in [SqlUserDefinedAggregateAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.server.sqlfunctionattribute.aspx)

---

It does help to reason about things if you consider why so many restrictions exist on indexed views.

The ones on aggregates have a pretty simple explanation - you're only allowed to use aggregates (such as `SUM` and `COUNT_BIG`) that have the property that SQL Server will be able to adjust the values, or add or remove rows from the index, based *purely* on the subset of rows that are the subject of the current transaction.

E.g. if the view has a row with `ID`=19, `COUNT_BIG`=5, and `SUM`=96, and a transaction deletes 3 rows with `ID` 19, whose `SUM` adds to 43, then it can update that row of the view to be `COUNT_BIG`=2 and `SUM`=53. Alternatively, if the transaction had deleted 5 rows with `ID`=19, it would have caused the row to be removed.

Note that in either case, we don't have to examine any other rows of the table to determine if they have `ID`=19.

So how could SQL Server hope to achieve similar functionality with a user defined aggregate? The current interface for user defined aggregates doesn't have the sort of support you'd need (it would need to have a trigger like interface also).